# Installing Drivers

Tags: 18.04, wireless, broadcom

I have recently swapped to Ubuntu 18.04 after being 'Windows 10'd'-  with a system that isn't up to running 10.
The standard download doesn't have a driver for my WiFi (Broadcom BCM43142). I have found a driver download for this, but I am having trouble getting it installed.

Comment: Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Start Software & Updates application. Open Additional Drivers tab you'll see your driver.

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS is you are using UEFI to get the driver working.